# Solr Replication: paths in confFiles Element?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to define a path (relative or absolute) for files in ReplicationHandler's confFile value?

For example:

```
<str name="confFiles">../../x.xml</str>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr replication for the Configuation files just works on the core conf folder.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_are_configuration_files_replicated.3F) for the Configuration replication.

With [SOLR-3809](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3809) Replication of files within the subfolders in the conf folder is supported. So if you have folders and files within the conf folder it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Configs of each core are checked depending on your settings in `solr.xml` file where you set your `instanceDir` attribute in cores tag. both for data - where indexes are stored and conf - where your configs are stored are checked automatically from `instanceDir` in `solr.xml`. So when you are doing replication, solr checks that specific folder and then checks names for the ones that you define `confFiles`.

Basically it checks a single folder for files, as it assumes that all of the configs for a specific core will be in that folder.

so giving path wont work